# Purple screen at the boot after installing Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: dual-boot

Friends:

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 64 Bits. I must say that I am sharing the 500GB hard disk drive with Windows Vista (250GB) and Ubuntu 13.04 (other 250GB). Once Ubuntu is installed (downloaded from the official page), it asks for reboot; I restart and the problem begins: I get GRUB (I think it is GRUB) and I have to choose between Ubuntu and Windows, I choose Ubuntu and... Purple screen after some seconds. Everything stops right there, nothing else. ¿Any ideas?

### Original Spanish Question

> Pantalla violeta al reiniciar después de instalar Ubuntu. 13.04
>
> amig@s,
>
> Acabo de instalar Ubuntu 13.04 64. Debo decir que comparto el
>   disco duro de 500gb entre Windows Vista (250gb) y Ubuntu 13.04 (otros
>   250 gb). Una vez instalo Ubuntu (descargado desde la página oficial),
>   me pide reiniciar; reinicio y ahí comienza el problema: me sale GRUB
>   (creo que es GRUB) y me da a elegir entre Ubuntu y Windows, elijo
>   Ubuntu y... pantalla violeta después de unos segundos. Ahí se para
>   todo, nada más. ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Computer is to old, the processor is to old. You might want go with 32 bit. It will probably make it work, but their is no promise. Good luck. I had the same problem with 10.04.

Comment: I'm trying with ubuntu 12.10 32bit. I'll tell you the result. Thank you, my friend!

Comment: Ehmmm.... I would appreciate a lot if you share with us your crystal ball's model. How did you know that the computer is too old? I can't see the computer specs anywhere! But you did!!! Damn! I need that technology in my hands!!! Please share the secret!!!

Comment: There is no crystal ball first of all, just learn from past experience. I would recommend going toward a .10 version other than .04 version. I had to go with Maverick meerkat  32 or 64 version a higher grade. Good luck :). No promise  toward it working but hopefully it will work.